Double Centralizer Property in simple ring without identity
In Lam's book, $\textit{A first course in noncommutative rings}$, Theorem 3.11 states:

Let $R$ be a simple ring, and $A$ be a nonzero left ideal. Let
$D = End({}_RA)$ (viewed as a ring of right operators on $A$). Then the natural
map $f: R \to End(A_D)$ is a ring isomorphism ($End(A_D)$ being viewed as a ring of left operators on $A$).

Is this statement true if we drop the condition that $R$ is a ring with identity? If it is not, would you give me a counterexample?
The way we use identity in the proof is as follows: to show $f$ is surjective, the author first showed $f(R)$ is a left ideal of $End(A_D)$. Now since $f(R)$ contains identity of $End(A_D)$, $f(R)=End(A_D)$.

$R$ still acts as a rng on $A_D$, so I believe it still embeds into $End(A_D)$ as a rng.
But if $R$ does not have an identity, then there's no way to conclude $A_D$ is a unital module, so there's no guarantee $f(R)$ contains the identity of $End(A_D)$.
Maybe there is a simpler example, but something that comes to mind immediately is Agata Smoktunowicz's famous example of a simple nil ring.  Clearly its image could not be all of $End(A_D)$ since one has identity and one does not.
